# Am I using a network that is too simple for the dataset/task?

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, rnn, pytorch, regularization

I am training an RNN to classify some high-frequency financial data. A very good performance on this data would be an accuracy of >52% or so.

I have around 650K training examples and 150K dev set examples (per cross-fold). Each training example has 50 time samples and a single binary output for the entire sequence. I am using **BCE as the loss** and the **AdamW optimizer**.

There are 17 features per time sample. The input tensor therefore is **(512 x 50 x 17)** -- that is batch *size x samples x features*

This is the network architecture:

```
V2LSTM(
  (lstm): LSTM(17, 32, batch_first=True, dropout=0.8)
  (fcl1): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=32, bias=True)
  (relu): ReLU()
  (drop): Dropout(p=0.8, inplace=False)
  (fcl2): Linear(in_features=32, out_features=1, bias=True)
  (sigmoid): Sigmoid()
)
Model params:
7617
```

Initially I had some difficulty with overfitting. I was using a **learning rate of 0.001**, **weight decay of 0.1** and **dropout of 70%**. I ran about 20 epochs. The overfitting is shown here.

[image]

I decided to reduce the **learning rate to 0.0001**, increase the **weight decay to 0.5** and **increase the dropout to 80%**. I needed to run more epochs but ultimately this worked well to reduce overfitting. It reduced the dev set loss, but didn't really improve the final dev set accuracy.

[image]

So it would appear to me that I have a bias problem rather than a variance problem and I should find ways to improve the network's learning of the training data. **My concern is that a more complicated network would lead to greater overfitting and I think I am out of options for further regularization without really hurting the network's ability to learn.**

Looking to get some guidance as to what I might try next.